# Вывод статей на страницу WP

Tags: wordpress

При выводе статей на страницу выподает лишние теги 'P'
Подскажите где ошибка?
Код используемый для выводи и разметка html

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <!-- subheader start -->
    <div class="cg__subHeader">
        <div class="cg__subHeader-overlay cg__bg-overlay"></div>
        <div class="cg__subHeader-img" style="background-image: url('<?= bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/subheader_03.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="cg__subHeader-contentWrapp">
            <div class="container cg__container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="cg__breadcrumbs">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
                            <li>Новости</li>
                        </ul><!--/.cg__breadcrumbs-->
                    </div><!--/.col-sm-6-->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="cg__subheader-title cg__text--right">
                            <h2 class="cg__elem--white">Новости</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/.col-sm-6-->
                </div><!--/.row-->
            </div><!--/.container-->
        </div><!--/.cg__subHeader-contentWrapp-->
        <div class="cg__bottom-mask">
            <svg class="cg__svgmask" width="2700px" height="57px" viewBox="0 0 2700 57" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                <polygon fill="#fff" style="fill:#f8f8f8" class="bmask-bgfill" points="0 57 0 0 1350 55.5 2700 0 2700 57"></polygon>
            </svg>
        </div><!--/.cg__bottom-mask-->
    </div><!--/.cg__subHeader-->
    <!-- subheader end -->

<?php
$temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <!-- news section start -->
    <div class="cg__pageSection cg__newsSection">
    <div class="container cg__container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
        <div class="cg__blogArchive">
            <div class="cg__blogArchive-item">
                <div class="cg__post-header">
                    <h3 class="cg__post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                </div><!--/.cg__post-header -->
                <div class="cg__post-body">
                    <div class="cg__post-imgWrapper">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="cg__post-img cg__hover-border">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div><!--/.cg__post-imgWrapper-->
                    <?php the_content(''); ?>
                </div><!--/.cg__post-body-->
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="cg__post-footer clearfix">
                    <div class="cg__readMore-btn">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="cg__btn">Читать дальше </a>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.cg__post-footer-->
                <div class="cg__post-links">
                    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></div>
                    <span>Published in</span>
                    <a href="/">Logistic</a>
                </div><!--/.cg__post-links-->
                <div class="cg__post-comments">
                    <a href="/">No Comments</a>
                </div><!--/.cg__post-comments-->
            </div><!--/.cg__blogArchive-item-->
        </div><!--/.cg__blogArchive-->
    </div><!--/.col-md-9 col-sm-9-->
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="cg__sidebar">
            <div class="cg__sidebar-search cg__widget">
                <form action="#" id="cg__search-form" method="get">
                    <input class="cg__search-form-input" type="text" placeholder="SEARCH ...">
                    <button type="submit" class="cg__search-form-submit glyphicon glyphicon-search" value="go"></button>
                </form>
            </div><!--/.cg__sidebar-search-->
            <div class="cg__sidebar-recent cg__widget">
                <h3 class="cg__sidebar-recent-title cg__widget-title">Recent Posts</h3>
                <ul class="cg__sidebar-recent-posts">
                    <li class="cg__sidebar-recent-post">
                        <a href="#" class="cg__sidebar-recent-thumb pull-left">
                            <img src="img-assets/post_01-150x150.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4 class="cg__sidebar-post-title">
                            <a href="news-single.html">Continually engage distributed infrastructures </a>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="cg__sidebar-post-text">
                            Collaboratively enhance out-of-the-box niche ma...
                        </div>
                    </li><!--/.cg__sidebar-recent-post-->
                    <li class="cg__sidebar-recent-post">
                        <a href="#" class="cg__sidebar-recent-thumb pull-left">
                            <img src="img-assets/post_02-150x150.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4 class="cg__sidebar-post-title">
                            <a href="news-single.html">Seamlessly initiate distinctive niches without</a>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="cg__sidebar-post-text">
                            Collaboratively enhance out-of-the-box niche ma...
                        </div>
                    </li><!--/.cg__sidebar-recent-post-->
                    <li class="cg__sidebar-recent-post">
                        <a href="#" class="cg__sidebar-recent-thumb pull-left">
                            <img src="img-assets/post_03-150x150.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4 class="cg__sidebar-post-title">
                            <a href="news-single.html">Distinctively promote real-time strategic theme areas</a>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="cg__sidebar-post-text">
                            Collaboratively enhance out-of-the-box niche ma...
                        </div>
                    </li><!--/.cg__sidebar-recent-post-->
                    <li class="cg__sidebar-recent-post">
                        <a href="#" class="cg__sidebar-recent-thumb pull-left">
                            <img src="img-assets/post_04-150x150.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <h4 class="cg__sidebar-post-title">
                            <a href="news-single.html">Quickly myocardinate enterprise-wide</a>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="cg__sidebar-post-text">
                            Collaboratively enhance out-of-the-box niche ma...
                        </div>
                    </li><!--/.cg__sidebar-recent-post-->

                </ul><!--/.cg__sidebar-recent-posts-->
            </div><!--/.cg__sidebar-recent-->
            <div class="cg__sidebar-archives cg__widget">
                <h3 class="cg__sidebar-recent-title cg__widget-title">ARCHIVES</h3>
                <ul class="cg__widget-menu">
                    <li><a href="news.html">November 2016</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.cg__sidebar-archives-->
            <div class="cg__sidebar-categories cg__widget">
                <h3 class="cg__sidebar-recent-title cg__widget-title">CATEGORIES</h3>
                <ul class="cg__widget-menu">
                    <li><a href="news.html">Logistic</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.cg__sidebar-categories-->
        </div> <!--/.cg__sidebar-->
    </div><!--/.col-md-3 col-sm-3-->
    </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
    </div><!--/.cg__pageSection-->
    <!-- news section end -->

    <!-- cta section start -->
    <div class="cg__ctaSection">
        <div class="container cg__container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
                    <div class="cg__cta-titleBlock cg__text--left">
                        <h2>We're ready to collect your package</h2>
                        <p>Uniquely redefine accurate architectures vis-a-vis front-end alignments.</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.col-md-10 col-sm-10-->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <a href="#" class="cg__btn cg__btn-block">GET A QUOTE</a>
                </div><!--/.col-md-2 col-sm-2-->
            </div><!--/.row-->
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </div><!--/.cg__ctaSection-->
    <!-- cta section end -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Пример на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите код, как вы выводите свой html, полностью.

Comment: https://codepen.io/vadim-chumachenko/pen/ErBmPO

Comment: Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос, добавив в него код. Вся информация должна быть прямо в вопросе.

Comment: не получается поставить код в пост так как выдает ошибку

Comment: Надо было сдвинуть весь код вправо на 4 пробела. Поправил ваш вопрос.

Comment: Ну это у вас так выводится `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` Что в нем?

Comment: У вас перед endwhile; выводится the_excerpt(), вот он и выводит этот текст

Comment: Спасибо что поправили) Дело в том что если я удаляю функцию <?php the_excerpt(); ?> тогда на странице выводиться всего лишь одна запись(только первая)